# SQL Query to output hyperlinks

Tags: sql, excel, csv, hyperlink

New to Stack Overflow but hoping you can give me some insight.

I have done the following query;

[image: My Query Screenshot]

And it acts as i wish when I right click the results headings and choose "Save Results As"

When I open my file I get a hyper link value in the "Image Bank Link".

[image: Hyperlink Screenshot]

However, if I run this query through a built in query process, the exported csv does not handle the hyperlink format.

Open to ideas.

Kind Regards
JT